# MDX choose previous quarter if selected one is not complete

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I am creating a parameter list in SSRS using MDX, and so I just want to list the completed quarters.  The way it works is we have "records" that get submitted on certain dates.  If the last date that it gets submitted is not equal to the quarter end date then restrict the parameter list to be up to the last quarter.

So The last submission was on Oct which is Quarter 3, but since October is not the end of the quarter, we want it to show the list upto quarter 2.  Here is my MDX for the drop down list

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
    [Date - Submitted].[Submitted   Year-Quarter].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
    [Date - Discharge].[Submitted Year-Quarter].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Quarter].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterValue]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterLevel]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Quarter].Children
   ,[Measures].[Records Count]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Records Cube]
WHERE 
  [Records].[Submission Status].&[Submitted];
```

any ideas on what I can add to this so that it can check whether it is the end of the quarter, and if not, just included [Submitted Year-Quarter of the one before this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have create two measures and check if both is non empty:

```
    WITH 

 Member [Measures].[MonthID] as
    [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Month].CurrentMember.Properties('Key')

 Member [Measures].[MonthNumber] as
    Right([Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Month].CurrentMember.Properties('Key'),2)

 Member [Measures].[IsLastMonth] as
    IIF(
        [Measures].[MonthNumber] / 3 - cint([Measures].[MonthNumber] / 3) = 0
        and [Measures].[Records Count],
        1,
        Null
    )    

SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[MonthID]
   ,[Measures].[MonthNumber]
   ,[Measures].[IsLastMonth]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    NULL:
    Order(
        NonEmpty(
            [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Month].[Month].Members,
            [Measures].[IsLastMonth]
        ),
    [Measures].[MonthID],
    BDESC
    ).Item(0)
 }  ON ROWS
FROM [Records Cube]
WHERE 
  [Records].[Submission Status].&[Submitted];
```

Comment: Your solution works great, since I am not super great with MDX, how can I put the year-quarter to display as well?  it is [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Fiscal Year-Quarter], I am trying to get it to display with your solutions.

Comment: Simply add: {[Date - Submitted].[Submitted Fiscal Year-Quarter].[Year].Members, [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Fiscal Year-Quarter].[Quarter].Members} * { NULL: ...

Comment: Sorry what I meant is how do I put the fiscal-year quarter but I want it to be distinct since I am creating a drop down list.  So each year quarter will display 3 times since there are three months in each quarters.  But so far your solution is working great, I just have that little kink to fix

Comment: Do mean a hierarchy view within the SSRS? There are two ways. 1. You have to use the Hierarchize function. 2. If you've already have all required attributes within a hierarchy, reuse it simply replace [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Month].[Month].Members with {[Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Month].[Year].Members,[Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Month].[Quarter].Members,[Date - Submitted].[Submitted Year-Month].[Month].Members} in my code.

Comment: So in SSRS, I use this code to generate a drop down list to list all the non empty year quarters, so it displays as for example
2014-Q1
2014-Q1
2014-Q1
2014-Q2
2014-Q2
2014-Q2
.
.etc
But I want it to display as 
2014-Q1
2014-Q2

they reason why it is display each quarter three times is because the set that is being returned is joined by the month year which has 3 per quarter.  Do you get what I mean?  By the way I have a hierarachy attribute of [Date - Submitted].[Submitted Fiscal Year-Quarter].[Year-Quarter] so I do not need to cross join year and quarter together.

Comment: Do not worry I figured that part with the help of the function Item() which you have used here.  So What I did is I created a set with the code above crossed joined with year-quearter.  Then I selected that sets last tail which I did a range, and retrieved the item of the item to get the last member in the quarter
NONEMPTY(Null:tail([DateQuarters],1).item(0).item(1),[measures].[record count])
 [DateQuarters] is the set I created using your code.

Thanks alot, I learned alot through your code